# Symfony4 : separate log files for different domains

Tags: php, symfony, monolog

I have 3 web domains (**first.com**, **second.com**, **third.com**) and I'm trying to have separate log files for each of these domains.

I'm using **php7.4**, **Symfony4** and **Monolog**, I managed to have the 3 log files, but so far every attempt I made just modified every log file, no matter which domain I was on.

I tried to use the **host** and **url** options, but it kept modifying all 3 files at the same time.

Here is my monolog.yaml file with different examples of what I tried :

```
monolog:
    handlers:
        main_first:
            host: "first.com"
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: first
            excluded_404s:
                # regex: exclude all 404 errors from the logs
                - ^/
        first:
            type: rotating_file
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/first/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            max_files: 30

        main_second:
            url: "second.com"
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: second
            excluded_404s:
                # regex: exclude all 404 errors from the logs
                - ^/
        second:
            type: rotating_file
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/second/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            max_files: 30

        main_third:
            type: fingers_crossed
            action_level: error
            handler: third
            excluded_404s:
                # regex: exclude all 404 errors from the logs
                - ^/
        third:
            type: rotating_file
            path: "%kernel.logs_dir%/third/%kernel.environment%.log"
            level: debug
            max_files: 30
```

Is there any way to tell Monolog to modify a specific file depending on the domain of the request ?

If not, how can I manage to do so without Monolog ?